is it possible to output the verbose info when using docker push to upload images
When I tried to using this command to upload some image to center hub:
➜  ~ docker push registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-public/prom/node-exporter:v1.8.2
The push refers to repository [registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-public/prom/node-exporter]
4f3f7dd00054: Preparing
6b83872188a9: Preparing
1e604deea57d: Preparing
denied: requested access to the resource is denied

is it possible to output the detail info of push? I have tried like this:
➜  ~ docker --verbose push registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-public/prom/node-exporter:v1.8.2 --verbose

also tried like this:
➜  ~ docker --debug push registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-public/prom/node-exporter:v1.8.2 --verbose
and read the docs of the docker command, seems did not mention the verbose log.
